# change where statement given a case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have a table which contains users info. with the columns:

- id_staff
- email
- id_supervisor
- id_branch
- id_department

and I want to select the information in this table depending on a variable like

```
DECLARE @user_type nvarchar(20) = 'manager'
```

How can I change the `where` statement based on the variable

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE 
(
   CASE WHEN @user_type = 'manager' THEN 
     id_branch = 3 AND id_department = 9
   ELSE
     id_supervisor = 15
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean logic. You seem to want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
    (@user_type = 'manager' AND id_branch = 3 AND id_department = 9)
    OR (@user_type <> 'manager' AND id_supervisor = 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `THEN` parts of `CASE` expressions produce **values**. They cannot produce futher boolean expressions. To resolve this, you must move all of the logic up to the `WHEN` parts of the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @User_type = 'manager' AND id_branch = 3 and id_deparment = 0
                    THEN 1
               WHEN @user_type <> 'manager' AND id_supervisor = 15 
                    THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case expression like this

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @user_type = 'manager' 
               THEN CASE WHEN id_branch = 3 AND id_department = 9
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE 0 END
               WHEN id_supervisor = 15
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: case *expression* **not** *statement* :)